# Trying to create a MonoGame Windows 7 desktop project

Tags: windows-7, xna, visual-studio-2012, monogame

I have Visual Studio 2012 open. In the Templates > Visual C# > Windows, I currently do not see a Monogame template. Could someone give me some pointers? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. In the Solution Explorer I see the following 3 projects...

- Lidgren.Network.Windows
- MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Windows
- MonoGame.Framework.Windows

Isn't there supposed to be a MonoGame project template that should be selectable to start off my project? Does MonoGame require XNA to be installed?

Basically I'm trying to do a helloworld. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you are viewing the source to MonoGame. You should install MonoGame using the [installer](http://monogame.codeplex.com/downloads/get/511666), that will put the MonoGame project templates in the right location for Visual Studio to locate them.